# for loop in Python creating a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a for loop. Introduce a value (p) into an empty list. I want to do a kind of vector that save me all source values of the math operations.

```
lista=list()
for index in len(lista+1):
 lista.append(p)
 index=index+1
print lista
```

Thx for your help

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Instead of keeping track of the loop iteration yourself, use http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: What's the point of the loop here? Are you trying to add more than one value? Adding a single value to a list is done simply by calling `lista.append(p)`.

Comment: Or, if you want to add n copies of a value, that's just `lista.extend(p * n)`.

Comment: You are (1) trying to add an int to a list (`lista+1`) and (2) trying to iterate over an int (`len(lista+1)`). Neither of these makes sense, and both result in errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lista=list()
for index in range(len(lista)):
 lista.insert(p)
 index=index+1
print lista
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to insert a value into an empty list it should look like this:

```
ps = []      # create the empty list
ps.append(p) # add the value p
```

or you could just do this which gives the same result `ps = [p]`

If you want to insert it n-times you can use a for loop like this:

```
ps = []
for i in range(n):
  ps.append(p)
```

or just do this which gives the same result `ps = n * [p]`

Comment: p have different values every time that the program did an operation

Comment: There is no way for p to change in your loop. We would need more context information to help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
lista = [i*i for i in range(N)]
print lista
```

or use:

```
for i in range(N)
   lista.append(i*i)
print lista
```

Comment: but I don't know the number of data could be 100 or 1000. It depends the time of running of the Program.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing `for index in range(len(lista) + 1):` instead of `for index in len(lista+1):`

To simplify your code, you can also do:

```
lista = list()
[p] * (len(lista) + 1)
```

Comment: maybe you mean `for index in range(len(lista)+1)`?